# How to calculate utc in local time on ubuntu with python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, nginx, time, ubuntu-18.04

I have a web application writen in python 3.8 running on an ubuntu server (18.04).
Requests to the server are processed by a nginx server.

It is possible to upload pdf and excel files and the website should show the date and time the files were uploaded.
This is working but the utc time is shown and I want the website to show the actual local time (Europe/Berlin UTC +1/+2). So I just tried to convert the time within the python code:

> utc_diff = 1 
> cur_time = time.time()

> if time.localtime(cur_time).tm_isdst:  # check summer / winter time 
> >> utc_diff = 2

> ... (datetime.fromtimestamp(round(timestamp)) + timedelta(hours=utc_diff))

or

> utc = datetime.utcnow()
> ltz = datetime.astimezone(utc)
> diff = str(ltz).split("+")
> diff = diff[1].split(":")

> ... datetime.fromtimestamp(round(timestamp)) + timedelta(hours=int(diff))

The problem is that I just can calcualte for example +2 hours but if I want to use any fucntions of the time or datetime module it just works on my local windows pc but not on the server.

The line `datetime.fromtimestamp(round(timestamp)) + timedelta(hours=int(diff))` is working locally and on the server.

How I have to code this to make it work on the server?

Comment: I don't think that's how you want to handle time zones. Instead, you'll want to get the user's time zone, then *localize* the server's UTC time to that for display to the user of the web app

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to do the time offset by hand. I think you want soemthing more like:

```
import time

now = time.time()
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(now)))
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime(now)))
```

Comment: That's nice to determine the time and timedelta but is still not working on the server.